# VelocityJS, velocity.ui and VueJS 2 issue in transitions

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, velocity.js

I'm trying to use Velocity.js inside my project, combining both Vue for the frontend and Laravel for the backend.

I tried to use VelocityUI plug-in to set sequences but, as it works fine in the "on enter" event, it do not on the "on leave" as there's no way to make it into e promise and call the "done" event after it... I event created my own promise without success.

Secondly, I'm unable to use premade effects from the UI package, because I can't chain them to this like $el.getElementsByTagName('p').velocity()... It do not find Velocity there... I tried to add it to Vue in many ways but can't find a way to do so...

Could you please help me with my issues or give me some clues as I looked almost everywhere without success.

Kind regards.

François Houlbrèque

Comment: Have you seen this example? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks And BTW, show your code which fails, so comeone can point at the source of your issues there.

Comment: It's exactly what I did, but I wanted to use predefined effects from Velocity.UI or the sequence system but it's not working, as I said, because it's not returning a promise, and weren't able to make it do "on complete" as I wished.

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample snippet and a pen that may help you.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      velocityUI: [
        "flash",
        "headShake",
        "jello",
      ],
      selected: "flash"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    expandBox() {
      var vm = this
      Velocity(vm.$refs.expandBoxComplete, vm.selected)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/velocity-animate@2.0/velocity.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/velocity-animate@2.0/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <!-- inline object literal -->
    <option v-for="velocity in velocityUI" v-bind:value="velocity">{{velocity}}</option>
  </select>
  <button @click="expandBox">animate!</button>
  <div ref="expandBoxComplete" class="box"></div>

</div>
```

and here is the pen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wQZQLJ

Comment: Can you provide some explanation of *how* this solves OPs problem?